# defining a variadic coordinate (tuple) type in C++17?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I wanted to define a variadic tuple type to represent coordinates. For example, for some magic type:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct CoordT {
  typedef std::tuple<_some_magic_> coord_type;
};
```

I'd like to have `CoordT<3>::coord_type` to be the 3-dimensional coordinate type:

```
std::tuple<double, double, double>
```

.

But I don't know how to use template programming to generate `N` repeated `double`s.

Can anyone please help explain how to write it?

Comment: @Justin Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::make_integer_sequence` to generate a pack of the appropriate length, then map the elements to doubles:

```
template <size_t n>
struct TupleOfDoubles {
    template <size_t... i>
    static auto foo(std::index_sequence<i...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(double(i)...);
    }
    using type = decltype(foo(std::make_index_sequence<n>{}));
};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7950876813128c55

Comment: Thanks! Could you add an example on how to use the `foo` function to create a tuple of doubles?

Comment: @tinlyx check the coliru link

Answer (score 2):

If you don't literally need a `std::tuple`, but just need something which acts like a tuple, use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct CoordT {
  typedef std::array<double, N> coord_type;
};
```

`std::array` has overloads for [`std::get<I>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get), [`std::tuple_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size), and [`std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_element). Most library and language facilities which accept a tuple-like element will support `std::array`, such as [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) and [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Answer (score 0):

Is too late to play?

If for you is acceptable to declare (no definition is needed) a variadic template function as follows

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto toIndexSeq (std::index_sequence<Is...> a)
   -> decltype(a);
```

and that the `coord_type` is defined in a `CoordT` specialization, you can write it as follows

```
template <std::size_t N,
          typename = decltype(toIndexSeq(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}))>
struct CoordT;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct CoordT<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { using coord_type = std::tuple<decltype((void)Is, 0.0)...>; };
```

The following is a full C++14 compiling example

```
#include <tuple> 
#include <type_traits> 

template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto toIndexSeq (std::index_sequence<Is...> a)
   -> decltype(a);

template <std::size_t N,
          typename = decltype(toIndexSeq(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}))>
struct CoordT;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct CoordT<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { using coord_type = std::tuple<decltype((void)Is, 0.0)...>; };


int main()
 {
   using t0 = std::tuple<double, double, double, double>;
   using t1 = typename CoordT<4u>::coord_type;

   static_assert( std::is_same<t0, t1>::value, "!" );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A very concise way to do this is by using [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) and [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct CoordT {
  using coord_type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::array<double, N>{}));
};
```

`std::tuple_cat` is [allowed to support tuple-like types](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/tuple#creation-13) such as `std::array`, but not guaranteed. However, every implementation I checked [supports this](https://godbolt.org/z/1hkLHR).